# Ignoring Android unit tests depending on SDK level

Tags: android, junit

Is there an annotation or some other convenient way to ignore junit tests for specific Android SDK versions? Is there something similar to the Lint annotation TargetApi(x)? Or do I manually have to check whether to run the test using the Build.VERSION?

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there is something ready but it pretty easy to create a custom annotation for this.

Create your custom annotation

```
@Target( ElementType.METHOD )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TargetApi {
    int value();
}
```

Ovverride the test runner (that will check the value and eventually ignore/fire the test)

```
public class ConditionalTestRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public ConditionalTestRunner(Class klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    public void runChild(FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
        TargetApi condition = method.getAnnotation(TargetApi.class);
        if(condition.value() > 10) {
            notifier.fireTestIgnored(describeChild(method));
        } else {
            super.runChild(method, notifier);
        }
    }
}
```

and mark your tests

```
@RunWith(ConditionalTestRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    @TargetApi(6)
    public void testMethodThatRunsConditionally() {
        System.out.print("Test me!");
    }
}
```

Just tested, it works for me. :)

Credits to: [Conditionally ignoring JUnit tests](http://blog.xebia.com/2012/10/02/conditionally-ignoring-junit-tests/)

Comment: Looks like a beautiful solution, but how do you get JUnit 4 to work with Android?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem without any Junit version, you have eventually change the test runner I guess. Which is the version that you're using?

Comment: I think it's JUnit 3.8. Android testing tools do not support JUnit 4: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

Comment: Now it's supported https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/AndroidJUnitRunnerUserGuide you can use it from Support Repository.

Comment: This worked for me when I tried it to solve a similar problem. However there's now the @SdkSuppress annotation which works too and it's clean and simple to use. See the answer to my Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865658/how-can-we-automatically-only-run-tests-on-newer-android-versions/45866924#45866924

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use JUnit's `assume` functionality:

```
@Test
fun shouldWorkOnNewerDevices() {
   assumeTrue(
       "Can only run on API Level 23 or newer because of reasons",
       Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23
   )
}
```

If applied, this effectively marks the test method as skipped.

This is not so nice like the annotation solution, but you also don't need a custom JUnit test runner.

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for an answer to this question, and haven't found a better way than to check the version. I was able to conditionally suppress the execution of test logic by putting a check in the following Android `TestCase` methods. However, this doesn't actually prevent the individual tests from executing. Overriding the `runTest()` method like this will cause tests to "pass" on API levels you know will not work. Depending on your test logic, you may want to override `tearDown()` too. Maybe someone will offer a better solution.

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.INFO)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "This feature is only supported on Android 2.3 and above");
        }
    } else {
        super.setUp();
    }
}

@Override
protected void runTest() throws Throwable {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        assertTrue(true);
    } else {
        super.runTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @mark.w's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866924/923920) is the path of least resistance:

> You might wanna take a look at [SdkSuppress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/filters/SdkSuppress.html) annotation. It has two methods -- maxSdkVersion and minSdkVersion which you could use depending on your need.

for example:

```
@Test
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void testMethodThatRunsConditionally() {
    System.out.print("Test me!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded answer of @Enrichman for Kotlin modern version. So, this is test runner class:

```
class ConditionalSDKTestRunner(klass: Class<*>?) : BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(klass) {
    override fun runChild(method: FrameworkMethod, notifier: RunNotifier) {
        // Annotation class could not have a base class of interface, so we can not group them.
        val testOnlyForTargetSDKCode = method.getAnnotation(TestOnlyForTargetSDK::class.java)?.sdkLevel?.code
        val testForTargetSDKAndBelowCode = method.getAnnotation(TestForTargetSDKAndBelow::class.java)?.sdkLevel?.code
        val testForTargetSDKAndAboveCode = method.getAnnotation(TestForTargetSDKAndAbove::class.java)?.sdkLevel?.code

        when {
            // If annotation exists, but target SDK is not equal of emulator SDK -> skip this test.
            testOnlyForTargetSDKCode != null && testOnlyForTargetSDKCode != Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ->
                notifier.fireTestIgnored(describeChild(method))
            // If annotation exists, but test SDK is lower than emulator SDK -> skip this test.
            testForTargetSDKAndBelowCode != null && testForTargetSDKAndBelowCode < Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ->
                notifier.fireTestIgnored(describeChild(method))
            // If annotation exists, but test SDK is higher than emulator SDK -> skip this test.
            testForTargetSDKAndAboveCode != null && testForTargetSDKAndAboveCode > Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ->
                notifier.fireTestIgnored(describeChild(method))
            // For other cases test should be started.
            else -> super.runChild(method, notifier)
        }
    }
}
```

Enum with exist SDKs in your project:

```
enum class SdkLevel(val code: Int) {
    SDK_24(24),
    SDK_25(25),
    SDK_26(26),
    SDK_27(27),
    SDK_28(28),
    SDK_29(29),
    SDK_30(30),
    SDK_31(31),
    SDK_32(32)
}
```

and annotations below:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class TestForTargetSDKAndAbove(val sdkLevel: SdkLevel)

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class TestForTargetSDKAndBelow(val sdkLevel: SdkLevel)

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class TestOnlyForTargetSDK(val sdkLevel: SdkLevel)
```

To use it just add `ConditionalSDKTestRunner` to your base android unit test class:

```
@RunWith(ConditionalSDKTestRunner::class)
abstract class BaseAndroidUnitTest
```

and necessary annotation for test to make it actual only for special sdk:

```
@Test
@TestForTargetSDKAndAbove(SdkLevel.SDK_31)
fun getConnectionInfo_positive_SDK31() {

@Test
@TestForTargetSDKAndBelow(SdkLevel.SDK_30)
fun getConnectionInfo_negative1_SDK30() {

@Test
@TestOnlyForTargetSDK(SdkLevel.SDK_29)
fun getConnectionInfo_negative1_SDK29() {
```

That's all. Thanks!