# How can we automatically only run tests on newer Android versions?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I discovered that one test, in particular, fails consistently on pre-KitKat devices. I believe it's related to the change in embedded WebView used on older Android devices (but perhaps this is mistaken). Anyway, back to my question: I'd like an elegant way to control whether a test is run depending on the version of Android that's running on the device.

Currently, I use code that short-circuits the test and passes it if the runtime is earlier than KitKat. Here's the relevant code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  assertTrue("Skipping this test as the Android version is too low.", true);
  return;
}
```

I've since tried to use two annotations in turn: `@TargetApi` and `@RequiresApi` e.g.

```
@Test
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void zimTest() {
    Log.v("kiwixTesting", "Running zimTest() on Android version: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    ...
}
```

In both cases, the test was run on my test devices (which include Android 4.3, 4.3, 4.4, and newer versions). I can tell because the test runner shows the test was run successfully, and the output of the following log message
`Log.v("kiwixTesting", "Running zimTest() on Android version: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);` appears in the log.

The full code is [here](https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-android/blob/master/app/src/androidTestKiwix/java/org/kiwix/kiwixmobile/tests/ZimTest.java) and I'm tracking the work [here](https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-android/issues/246)

Can anyone suggest a better approach than mine please? Thank you.

Comment: Someone posted an answer that disappeared shortly afterwards, with a link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654249/ignoring-android-unit-tests-depending-on-sdk-level/17654337#17654337 I did implement a version of this custom annotation and it worked well. However the accepted answer (using @SdkSuppress) was cleaner and shorter so I scrapped my custom annotation to use @SdkSuppress instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at [SdkSuppress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/filters/SdkSuppress.html) 
annotation. It has two methods -- maxSdkVersion and minSdkVersion which you could use depending on your need.

Comment: Thank you, it's as simple as adding `  @SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)`